# Chef Apache2 web_app Configuration

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to provision a Apache using chef using the [Opscode cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2). I have configured my default attributes like this below. I have created a template file `/vagrant/sites-available/sof.conf` (and even `/vagrant/sites-available/sof.conf.erb` just to be sure).

It never evaluates the template or enables the site. What is wrong?

(Using chef-server if that changes anything)

```
{
    "overrides": {},
    "defaults": {
        "apache2": {
            "web_app": {
                "name": "sof",
                "server_name": "localhost",
                "server_aliases": [],
                "docroot": "/vagrant/web"
            },
            "user": "www-data",
            "dir": "/vagrant",
            "log_dir": "/vagrant/logs/http"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the examples in the [doc](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2#web_app) it seems that you can declare web_apps only from within other cookbooks not via node attributes?

Comment: @cmur2 You are right. If you suggest that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the examples section in the [doc](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2#web_app) it seems that you can declare `web_app`s only from within other cookbooks not via node attributes.